# External status checks in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I want to add external status checks for my project on gitlab. For that I followed this [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/status_checks.html) but for my project the option to add status checks is not showing in the **settings -> General -> merge requests** section. Also When I am trying to add it through api as shown in this [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/status_checks.html#:%7E:text=50.787Z%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22code_owner_approval_required%22%3A%20false%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D-,Create%20external%20status%20check,-You%20can%20create), I am getting "Unauthorized" as response. I have maintainer access for the project and I have given complete api access to my token. I even tried with project access token but the response was same. 
Any help from the community would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a GitLab Ultimate tier subscription?

Answer (score 0):

The external status checks is a Ultimate tier feature. If the setting is not displayed, this is most likely because you do not have an Ultimate tier subscription entitlement on this project.